# ASP.net MVC - Where did the Password retrieval go?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, password-retrieval

Was it my imagination or did the earlier releases of ASP.net MVC have built in password retrieval?

I'm not seeing it in version 1.0

Comment: Yes i know i'm just being lazy and I should just roll my own.  But really - why bother when there was a perfectly good version available?

Comment: Did you mean that asp.net login control with that built-in pass retrieval functionality?

Answer (score 0):

did you mean control? you can use standard ASP.NET membership related controls

and don't forget about [Authorize] attribute